# why R does not calculate the correlation when one value is NA?

Tags: r, binary, correlation

I have two directories. I used the code given below to calculate the spatial correlation between these files and it worked well. So basically I want to tell R:
even if there is NA between two pixels(in the two files), it shall ignore it but calculate for the rest (11 pixels).

```
    for(i in 1:length(dir1)){
    file_tot[,,i,1] <- dir1[i], numeric(), size = 4 , signed = T
   file_tot[,,i,2] <- dir2[i], numeric(), size = 4 ,  signed = T
   }
```

Comment: The behavior of `cor` with `NA` values is completely documented at `?cor`, if one bothers to read it. Pay particular attention to the `use` argument, if you need to be pointed to the exact spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `cor` by default `use="everything"`, which includes `NA`.  Read `?cor`, specifically the `use` argument to determine which value you should set it to for your particular situation.